# Is it possible to render array of components?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Home extends React.Component { 
     render() {
        const array = [<Hello />,<Hello />,<Hello />]
        return {array.map((item) => {
            return item
        })}
     }
}
```

I've got the code like above and how to render array that has got a React components yet. It it possible or maybe there is other approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: this does not work of course

Comment: return array; should also work in this simple case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `{...}` wrapping after return with `(...)`, or omit it. Nevertheless, as stated out by various comments a simple `return array;` is enough. Following code should give you the desired result.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const array = [
      <Hello name="John" />,
      <Hello name="Max" />,
      <Hello name="Alex" />
    ];

    return array;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
Please take note, that following notation (directly returning an array) will only work with React 16, previous versions require a wrapping with a `<div>` or a `<span>` element (Thanks for hint by @BrianGenisio).

For more interactive mode, check out this **[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p93n6xk25q)**

Comment: @JuanMendes Just wanted to point out which part of the code wasn’t working, but you are totally right, so I edited the answer :-)

Comment: It's important to note that returning an array is supported in React 16, but anything earlier requires a wrapper element (like a `<div>` or a `<span>`).

Comment: @BrianGenisio I updated the answer, thank you for the hint!